# Android - application depending on own api - server offline

Tags: java, android, eclipse, downtime

I don't know if this is the right place to post but I am completly lost.

My application, that is relying on an api from my own vps(that is down for 4 hours now), is not working anymore.

I have contacted my host, but they aren t moving fast and I have no backup of my vps content.

Many users are bad reviewing my application and I'm starting to be crazy about it.

Is there any solution to avoid bad reviewing you could advice me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, If I was a user and I would see a crash issue I would downvote too, but I wouldn't be so annoyed if your app gives me something like

```
"We are improving something bla bla"
```

and I would wait for it.

It's best check those situations such as downtime,no internet etc and let the user know about it.